# $\Delta u = f(u,x)$ in $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has at most one solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I want to show that the PDE $\Delta u = f(u,x)$ in $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with the boundary value $u = \varphi$ on $\partial \Omega$ has at most one solution under the following conditions:

1. $\Omega$ is a bounded Domain
2. $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R} \times \overline{\Omega}$ and continously differentiable in u so that $f_u(u,x) \ge 0$

I believe the maximum principle might be applicable here, but I'm unsure about how to prove that $\Delta (u-v) \ge 0$ for 2 solutions of the equation

If anyone could provide a hint on how to solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It is known that its wrong for unspecified boundaries, boundary values and production terms as the right side.  Think of it as the steady state of a diffusion problem, the boundary must be accessible, on a smooth boundary the values must be of limited variation (counter example by Hadamard) and net flow inward negative or zero and the production term must allow for an final equilibrium state.

Comment: @RolandF , It's rather strange that this statement is unprovable, since it was assigned to us at university. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is true and has been asked before https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788874/showing-uniqueness-of-solution-to-a-non-linear-poisson-problem/4789035#4789035